# What is the correct pruning strategy for finding the power set of a list of numbers using DFS?

Tags: python, depth-first-search

Question:

> Given an integer array **nums** that may contain duplicates, return all possible
> subsets (the power set).
>
> The solution set must not contain duplicate subsets. Return the solution in any order.
>
> Example 1:
> Input: nums = [1,2,2]
> Output: [[],[1],[1,2],[1,2,2],[2],[2,2]]
>
> Example 2:
> Input: nums = [0]
> Output: [[],[0]]

This is my code:

```py
def dfs(nums, result, index, subset):
    result.append(subset.copy())
    if index == len(nums):
        return
    for i in range(index, len(nums)):
        if i > 0 and nums[i] == nums[i - 1]:
            continue
        subset.append(nums[i])
        dfs(nums, result, i + 1, subset)
        subset.pop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # nums = [4, 4, 4, 1, 4]
    nums = [1, 2, 2]
    result = []
    dfs(nums, result, 0, [])
    print(result)
```

I cannot find the correct pruning strategy.

If I input [1,2,2], my output is [[], [1], [1, 2], [2]], so it's pruning too much.

Answer (score -1):

I have made two minor modifications to your code (see comments):

```
def inList(ls,x):   
# corrects for same sequence of numbers  
# appearing as different element
  for y in ls:
    if sorted(y) == sorted(x):
      return True
  
  return False

def dfs(nums, result, index, subset):
    if not inList(result,subset): # check if new subset is already in power set
      result.append(subset.copy())
    if index == len(nums):
        return
    for i in range(index, len(nums)):
        if i > 0 and nums[i] in nums[index:i - 1]: # avoid adding same number
            continue
        subset.append(nums[i])
        dfs(nums, result, i + 1, subset)
        subset.pop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    nums = [1, 2, 2, 1, 2]
    result = []
    dfs(nums, result, 0, [])
    print(result) #[[], [1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 2], [1, 2, 2, 1], [1, 2, 2, 1, 2], [1, 2, 2, 2], [1, 2, 1], [1, 1], [2], [2, 2], [2, 2, 2]]
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: i think it is wrong

Comment: I think it is incredible that (a) you request power sets for sets with repeating elements (b) you attempt to reconstruct an algo which is already clearly defined https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/recursive-program-to-generate-power-set/  (c) you say 'I think it is wrong' without providing a code run for which the answer does not work

Comment: Sorry, I mistook the title and mistook “[1, 2, 2, 1, 2]” for “[1,2,2]"

Comment: your answer is right

Comment: My answer is an attempt to correct a very inefficient way to produce the power set. Please do some basic research so that you don’t try to reinvent the wheel. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

This is how I decided to do it to solve the problrm desribed in my question:

```py
def dfs(nums, result, index, subset):
    result.append(subset.copy())
    if index == len(nums):
        return
    for i in range(index, len(nums)):
        if i > index and nums[i] == nums[i - 1]:# it's should "i>index" not "i>0"
            continue
        subset.append(nums[i])
        dfs(nums, result, i + 1, subset)
        subset.pop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    nums = [4, 4, 4, 1, 4]
    # nums = [1, 2, 2]
    nums.sort()
    result = []
    dfs(nums, result, 0, [])
    print(result)
```

Comment: Are you trolling, or are you a genuine contributor?

Comment: I edited to avoid misunderstandings of "final". Keep in mind that you get to decide what you find most useful, but not what the best answer is (which could be confused with whatever you mean by "final answer"). That is what voting is for. Also, consider explaining the benefits of the shown solution. How does it work and why does that help?